# How to make a border with both a solid line and a gradient?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make a border around a div that has both a solid line and a gradient border. (No, it won't be as ugly as my sample image but I thought it would help more if I could at least show something resembling what I'm trying to achieve.) How do I do that? If I wanted two or more opposing gradients as a border around the same div, how would I do that? If you can clean up my original code any, I wouldn't be offended. I want this as clean, compliant, and cross-browser as possible. It's to be used in a mobile app, not a webpage, but I'm sure the finished code would apply to anything that accepts CSS code. Thanks for any help offered.

Here's what I have so far. Sample image provided for intended look.

[image: Art sample of desired finished look.]

```
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
-webkit-border-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    (top, rgba(255,224,122,1) 0%,rgba(153,119,0,1) 15%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 39%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 58%,rgba(132,117,66,1) 59%,rgba(255,249,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
-moz-border-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    (top, rgba(255,224,122,1) 0%, rgba(153,119,0,1) 15%, rgba(35,35,35,1) 39%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 58%, rgba(132,117,66,1) 59%, rgba(255,249,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
-o-border-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    (top, rgba(255,224,122,1) 0%, rgba(153,119,0,1) 15%, rgba(35,35,35,1) 39%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 58%, rgba(132,117,66,1) 59%, rgba(255,249,204,1) 100%); /* Opera */
border-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    (to bottom, rgba(255,224,122,1) 0%,rgba(153,119,0,1) 15%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 39%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 58%,rgba(132,117,66,1) 59%,rgba(255,249,204,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe07a', endColorstr='#fff9cc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 2 diferent background-images, one for the inner background and the other for a background that takes the place of the border (notice that we still need to define the border, but set to transparent).

Now, the solid border can be done with a box-shadow: inset:

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border: solid 10px transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(tomato, green, yellow), 
                    linear-gradient(to right, yellow, blue, tomato);
  background-origin: padding-box, border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Can it take multiple gradient declarations or only two?

Comment: You mean multiple steps in the gradients ? You can do whatever you want, I have updated the snippet.

Comment: No, I know about colour steps in gradients. I mean have a purple/pink gradient 3 pixels wide surrounded by a red/gold gradient 5 pixels wide.